# how to debug hive on IBM Analytics Engine?

Tags: hive, ibm-cloud, analytics-engine

I'm trying to debug a Hive job running on IBM Analytics Engine (IAE).

I have tried the following instructions: https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/150214/how-to-enable-debug-hive-cli-logging.html

```
hive -hiveconf hive.log.file=debug_hive_<date>.log -hiveconf hive.log.dir=/tmp/hivedebug/ 
-hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,DRFA
```

However, no log file was created.

As IAE is an IBM customised HDP environment, I would like to know what are the specific instructions for debugging a hive query on IBM Analytics Engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

1. Change Ambari UI->Hive->Advanced hive-log4j

   - from `"hive.root.logger=INFO,RFA"`
   - to `"hive.root.logger=DEBUG,RFA"`
2. Run a hive query
3. SSH into the cluster, find the log file in: `/tmp/clsadmin/hive.log`